# Docker should throw an error when "package.json" is not found but no error is thrown

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, package.json

I am learning Docker and created a very simple image that creates a container with node dependencies downloaded.

**See the docker image (Dockerfile) below:**

```
FROM node:14-alpine
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"] here
```

The directory has the following files `Dockerfile`, `index.js`, `package.json`. All three files are at the same level.

**when I run `docker build .`, I expect the step 2 to throw an error indicating `package.json` was not found as the temporary container created from step 1 should not have the `package.json` file, but I do not get this error**, instead the build is completed successfully. Could someone explain why does the build is completed successfully and I don't get any error?

**See the output from the build below:**

```
[+] Building 4.2s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                              docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 95B                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14-alpine                                                                             0.9s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:14-alpine@sha256:434215b487a329c9e867202ff89e704d3a75e554822e07f3e0c0f9e606121b33                       2.6s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:14-alpine@sha256:434215b487a329c9e867202ff89e704d3a75e554822e07f3e0c0f9e606121b33                       0.0s
 => => sha256:4cf6a83c0e2af3c780abcda02cc33f9e812fdcb40b610ed1838281cc9ab94ec8 2.43MB / 2.43MB                                                0.2s
 => => sha256:434215b487a329c9e867202ff89e704d3a75e554822e07f3e0c0f9e606121b33 1.43kB / 1.43kB                                                0.0s
 => => sha256:3380ed827b250d2db2bd38c15f090af2b303b3c9ebb42f5927cb5b9adeea7a6e 1.16kB / 1.16kB                                                0.0s
 => => sha256:d561716d42b6a03639723c382c62977347ed62f13925e836614583253308e6c3 6.45kB / 6.45kB                                                0.0s
 => => sha256:c41833b44d910632b415cd89a9cdaa4d62c9725dc56c99a7ddadafd6719960f9 3.26MB / 3.26MB                                                0.2s
 => => sha256:683339ce8d6b9be2ca150a8de67b895e20ea5594b91d3911c95b0b8fea3e314c 36.99MB / 36.99MB                                              1.3s
 => => extracting sha256:c41833b44d910632b415cd89a9cdaa4d62c9725dc56c99a7ddadafd6719960f9                                                     0.1s
 => => sha256:686172e40c38722891b4004f55f6447548c8367968ac523a612591e0d92f9db3 447B / 447B                                                    0.3s
 => => extracting sha256:683339ce8d6b9be2ca150a8de67b895e20ea5594b91d3911c95b0b8fea3e314c                                                     1.2s
 => => extracting sha256:4cf6a83c0e2af3c780abcda02cc33f9e812fdcb40b610ed1838281cc9ab94ec8                                                     0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:686172e40c38722891b4004f55f6447548c8367968ac523a612591e0d92f9db3                                                     0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN npm install                                                                                                                     0.7s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:9ffbc17f35fbca106a7a540b8433b8e5144d792244a35aa140d1c57bd1b8387c
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no `package.json`? Do you have a volume/bind mount? What happens if you `RUN ls` ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `npm install` in that image does not return an error code when `package.json` is missing.

Try starting a shell in that image and running `npm install`, then inspecting the exit code:

```
$ docker run --rm -it node:14-alpine sh
/ # npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm WARN !invalid#2 No description
npm WARN !invalid#2 No repository field.
npm WARN !invalid#2 No README data
npm WARN !invalid#2 No license field.

up to date in 0.208s
found 0 vulnerabilities

/ # echo $?
0
```

The key part is that last line, which shows that despite the warnings on output, the command completes successfully.

Since the command doesn't exit with an error, Docker believes it is successful and continues to build the image.

---

Note that this behavior seems to have changed with more recent versions of `npm`. For example, using the latest image:

```
$ docker run --rm -it node:20-alpine sh
/ # npm install
npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-07T01_02_38_828Z-debug-0.log
/ # echo $?
1
```

So if you were to use that version of the image it would fail as you expect.